# How to disable varnish on apache2 with ubuntu?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, varnish

I installed and setted up varnish using [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-varnish-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04--3)

Basically, I changed the port to 8080,

I want to disable varnish, so I thought I will change back to port 80 and thats it, varnish it's listening to 8080,

The thing is that I edited:

sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf:

```
#Listen 80
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 # it was 8080
Listen 127.0.0.1:80 # it was 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

And then, sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> # it was 8080
```

The problem was when restarting apache2, I got this error

```
 * Stopping HTTP accelerator varnishd                                                [ OK ] 
 * Starting HTTP accelerator varnishd                                                [ OK ] 
root@funcook:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                            AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/ports.conf:6
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

So I changed back to 8080 and restarting apache fired no errors,

Any idea what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that varnish is listening to port 80.

You can check it by issuing as root:

```
netstat -natpe |grep 80
```

to see if the port is in use.

If it is, you have to **stop varnish** (if it is varnish using the port 80 -most probable-) **or change it's port** and restart.

In other words, in the guide where it says:

> sudo nano /etc/default/varnish
>
> Uncomment all of the lines under “DAEMON_OPTS”—under Alternative 2,
>   and make the configuration match the following code:
>
> DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
>
> ```
>          -T localhost:6082 \
>          -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
>          -S /etc/varnish/secret \
>          -s malloc,256m"
> ```

the -a option says in which port varnish is listening... and is 80, is not possible both services to open a socket in the same port.

> We found after discussing the problem that ip should be rolled back in **ports** file too, as the guide asked to change it to listen on 127.0.0.1 instead of any public interface. The guide says:
>
> sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
>
> Change the port number for both the NameVirtualHost and the Listen line to port 8080, and the virtual host should only be accessible from the localhost. The configuration should look like this:
>
> NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
>   Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

Should be rolled back to Listen *:80 or Listen :80 for being publicly accessible again

Comment: The thing is that just checked `sudo nano /etc/default/varnish` and those lines are commented...  ¿?

Comment: Take a look with netstat to see which process is using your port so you can get to a better conclusion. The what I posted after is a hint related to what you are working with, but we don't know yet.

Comment: This is the output http://pastebin.com/KjvjeMSw. I also tried to stoping varnish using `sudo service varnish stop` and restarting the apache2 with no errors, but the site didn't resolve..

Comment: `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          5572515     27649/varnishd`
 

Varnish is listening on that port. So, if you need to get apache up. Stop varnish, start apache (it should work) and then take a look on where in the configuration varnish is configured with port 80.

I'm not sure in ubuntu, on debian 8 (systemd) I found that is in the varnish init script hardcoded

Comment: I tried, and it didn't output errors, but the site wasn't resolving... ¿?

Comment: Do you think I should try to uninstall varnish? http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/v/varnish/uninstall/index.html

Comment: No need to uninstall if it already released the port, just check with netstat if apache is using now the port.

Was it working before you installed varnish? It calls my attention that you have both VirtualHost and NameVirtualhost, but I haven't used apache for a while, so I don't know if it is ok or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27750/discussion-between-toni-michel-caubet-and-ignivs).